# RxJava for-loop with async methoods?

Tags: android, rx-java

I am learning to use RxJava with Android. In my project, I have a single situation where I get a `List` of items from the server, and I need to get the details of each item, before returning the response to the UI.

The problem is: I am not sure how to `sync` the API calls that are called inside the `for loop`. I want the end result returned to the UI only after all calls in the `foor loop` complete.

Any hints are **highly appreciated**.

Sample code:

```
Observable<List<Favorite>> result = ApiWrapper.getFavorites(userData)
            .flatMap(new Func1<List<Favorite>, Observable<List<Favorite>>>() {
              @Override
              public Observable<List<Favorite>> call(@NonNull final List<Favorite> response) {
                for(int i = 0; i < response.size(); i++){
                  getDetailsForFavoriteItem(response.get(i));
                }
                return Observable.just(response);              
              }
            });

private Observable<Favorite> getDetailsForFavoriteItem (Favorite item){
  return ApiWrapper.getDetails(item.getId())
        .flatMap(new Func1<FavoriteDetailsResponse, Observable<Favorite>>() {
              @Override
              public Observable<Favorite> call(@NonNull final FavoriteDetailsResponse response) {
                item.setParam1(response.getParam1());
                item.setParam2(response.getParam2);
                //so on
                return Observable.just(item)//!!!issue is here ! I want this return to be called only after all the details (in the for loop) have been called              
              }
            });
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, your API in `getDetailsForFavoriteItem()` is not called because you are not subscribing to an `Observable`.

Second, it would be better to `flatMap` your first response into one `Observable<Favorite>` and then `flatMap` it again to get a details for it. Something like this:

```
    Observable<List<Favorite>> result = ApiWrapper.getFavorites(userData)
            .flatMapIterable(favorites -> favorites)
            .flatMap(favorite -> getDetailsForFavoriteItem(favorite))
            .toList();
```

You can even make parallel calls to get your details by:

```
    Observable<List<Favorite>> result = getFavorites()
            .flatMapIterable(favorites -> favorites)
            .flatMap(favorite -> getDetailsForFavoriteItem(favorite)
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()), maxConcurrentCalls) // be sure to limit your maxConcurrentCalls or you might get OOM error
            .toList();
```

Comment: Thank you for suggestion, I took the approach indicated by the second snippet.